merging of csv files has changed the date format of date column
I am using a below script to combine several files into one.
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' InterfaceStatistics*.csv > /home/vikrant_singh_rana/nfv/merge/InterfaceStatistics_merge_file.csv

files are getting merged but the date format is being changed.. see column collectTime
circle,collectTime,item,collint,beginTime,duration,endTime,ifIn
Malaysia,20240519131607,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0110PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,20240519131607,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0110PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,20240519131607,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0110PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,20240519131607,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0110PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,20240519131607,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0110PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,20240519131607,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0110PEXP12/COMPUTE


circle,collectTime,item,collint,beginTime,duration,endTime,ifIn
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP12/COMPUTE
Malaysia,2.02405E+13,PLMN-PLMN/CBIS-A0112PEXP15/COMPUTE

Looking for some help to keep the date column format intact.
I am running this script on cloud shell environment.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that the date field is being treated as a real number field.
